# Gradle Android: how to add custom apk task before apk sign?

Tags: android, gradle

I try to use gradle to build my android app, so far it was good, I was able to add my custom tasks between default ones in base build flow using dependsOn, doLast, etc.
But it seems there are some internal tasks which are tightly linked with each other and its hard to customize them... For example, I can add my task after "dex" task, or after "packageApplication" task, but packaging and signing task seems to be hard to split.
For security reasons my app needs to use third party lib which does some preprocessing of APK, before it gets signed and zipaligned.
How can I do that? If I add my custom task after "dex" - its too early (no apk yet), if I add it after "packageApplication" task - its too late (apk is already signed).
Maybe there is a way to hack task tree, but looking into https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy doesn't seem to be so easy to do.
It would be nice if packageApp task was separated from signing task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to not setup any signing, so that the packageApplication task generates an unsigned apk.

Then you can add an apk-processing task, after which you'll have to add a custom apk signing step, and then link the zipalign task to its output.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I'll try to do that... it would be great if tasks were more atomic and reusable, maybe in some future versions of android plugin :)

Comment: I tried to copy a part of BasePlugin packageApp task (the one which is related to sign & zipalign) to my project in order to add my custom sign & zipalign, but I encountered some issue - getSdkParser() method seem to have package access and I can't set the path like default task does since the method is not visible: zipAlignTask.conventionMapping.zipAlignExe = { getSdkParser().zipAlign } do you have any ideas how to workaround this?

Comment: nevermind that ) I managed to do it via environment variable manualZipAlignTask.zipAlignExe = new File(System.env.ANDROID_HOME, "tools${File.separator}zipalign.exe");

Comment: yeah, custom signing tasks worked, though it wasn't very easy :) I had to remove signature from apk first, because the plugin signs debug variants with debug cert and I didn't find the way to disable it.